# Anchor Tag automatically calling href Without Click in Codeiginitor

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here in My View:

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" data- toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
<span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<?php 
foreach($site as $sites)
{
echo '<li ><a href="'.redirect(base_url().'shop/viewSiteId',$sites->site_id).'">"'.$sites->site_title.'"</a> </li>';
}
?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php 
}
?>
```

i want to redirect when user click on $sites->site_title 
but how it working is it automatically redirects to url

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here"<li><a href='shop/viewSiteId?id=".$sites->site_id."'>".$sites->site_title."</a></li>";
```

and get that id by using GET method

Comment: In view "<li><a href='shop/viewSiteId?id=".$sites->site_id."'>".$sites->site_title."</a></li>";   In controller $id=$this->input->get('id');

Answer (score 0):

A `redirect` is the programmatic way to send a browser to a URL. In other words, a call to `redirect` is like clicking a link. They are not intended to work together in the way you have tried.

```
<?php 
foreach($site as $sites) : ?>
   <li>
     <a href='<?= base_url("shop/viewSiteId?={$sites->site_id}"); ?>'><?=$sites->site_title; ?></a>
   </li>
<?php endforeach;
```

If you are not familiar with the syntax, know that `<?=` is the shortcut way to write `<?php echo`

I've also used [PHP Alternative Syntax for Control Structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) and dropped in and out of the PHP processor a bunch of times. For me, that is the easier way to read and write this kind of thing. (Your mileage may vary.)